# Javascript - using in function defined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute this function and use the variable outside the function, but inside an each function. How can I get this to work?

```
$('.social').each(function() {
    url = "http:www.google.com";
    bit_url(url);    
    $(element).append(urlshortened);
});

function bit_url(url) {
        var url = url;
        var username = "...";
        // bit.ly username
        var key = "...";
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten",
            data : {
                longUrl : url,
                apiKey : key,
                login : username
            },
            dataType : "jsonp",
            success : function(v) {
                urlshortened = v.data.url;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is `element`? (As in `$(element).append(urlshortened)`)

Comment: which *variable* ? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: any element, it's doesn't matter

Comment: which variable are you talking about ? please be more specific

Comment: the variable urlshortener will defined within the function bit_url

Comment: this url should I use when the each function is execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "A" in Ajax stands for Asynchronous code won't work like that, you need callbacks.

```
function bit_url(url) {
   [...]
   //return the Deffered object
   return $.ajax({ [...]
}

$('.social').each(function() {
    [...]
    //attach a `done` callback to the returned $.ajax's Deferred instance
    bit_url(url).done(function(v) {
        $(element).append(v.data.url);
    });
});
```

[`Deferred.done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) is an equivalent to `$.ajax`'s `success`, I've attached the `done` handler inside the `.each` scope so your callback can access all variables from the `.each` scope.

Though, if `$(element)` is always the same element, you will be fine with @JohnJohnGa's answer by putting the `append` inside the success handler.

I assume you want to replace anchors' `href` inside the `.each` due to the question nature, so you'd store a reference to the link inside of the `.each` and use that reference inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the result in the `success` function

```
success: function (v) {
    urlshortened = v.data.url;
    $(element).append(urlshortened)
}
```

So your code will be:

```
$('.social').each(function () {
    url = "http:www.google.com";
    bit_url(url);
});

function bit_url(url) {
    var url = url;
    var username = "...";
    // bit.ly username
    var key = "...";
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten",
        data: {
            longUrl: url,
            apiKey: key,
            login: username
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (v) {
            $(element).append(v.data.url);
        }
    });
}
```